# Ограничение ввода в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, на примере как сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить в ячейки только {-1,0,1}

Comment: В каждую ячейку можно вставить `QWidget` (`setCellWidget()`). Вы можете вставить туда `QSpinBox` с органичениями [-1;1]

Comment: Можете сказать, где это нужно прописывать?

Comment: При создании таблицы. Если пользуетесь дизайнером, то в конструкторе класса, в котором присутствует данная таблица